# Is there a way to create instance that has no default constructor from another class constructor's body?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a class instance with no default constructor from another class' constructor but not passing them as class initializers. Here is a sample code of what I am trying to do:

```cpp
class Device {
public:
  Device(const PhysicalDevice& device) { ... }
};

class Renderer {
public:
  Renderer() {
    auto physicalDevice = getPhysicalDevice();
    device = Device(physicalDevice); // <-- this causes me a problem
  }

  PhysicalDevice getPhysicalDevice();

  Device device;
};
```

Because I create a Device object and assign it to the member variable `device`, I am copying the temporary object to member variable, which means that temporary object needs to be destroyed.

Is there a way I can get rid of the temporary object and just initialize device directly?

Answer (score 3):

You can write using a mem-initializer list like:

```
class Renderer {
public:
  Renderer() : device( getPhysicalDevice() ) {
  }

  PhysicalDevice getPhysicalDevice();

  Device device;
};
```

As for your constructor definition then in this statement:

```
device = Device(physicalDevice);
```

it is supposed that the data member device was already created using the default constructor (that was not defined) before passing the control to the constructor body.  So the compiler issues an error.

Comment: I think Vlad meant `getPhysicalDevice()`.

Comment: I wish there was another way to do this because this is one example. There are cases where I want to create a variable, set it to another member, then use that member as argument for another member variable. Like, what if `physicalDevice` is also a member variable? 

I think I am going to add a function like `setPhysicalDevice` to my device function.

Comment: @Gasim That's possible, if you declare the variables in the order they need to be initialized in.

Answer (score 2):

Use an *initializer list* for the constructor:

```
Renderer()
    : device{ getPhysicalDevice() }
{
    /* Empty */
}
```

This will be used to *initialize* the `device` object, rather than having it be default-initialized and then assign to it.